# Closed and bounded subsets of twice continuously differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Can you show that a closed and bounded set $A$ of $C_{2}[0,1]$ is has a compact closure in $C_{1}[0,1]$? I think the Arzela theorem must be invoked here, and it suffices to check that $A$ is equicontinuous, for which it suffices to check that the set of derivatives of functions in $A$ is uniformly bounded. But how do you do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $A$ is bounded in $C_{2}[0,1]$, then there exists a constant $M$ such that
$$
             |f'(x)| \le M,\;\; |f''(x)| \le M,\;\; \mbox{ for all } x \in [0,1],\; f \in A.
$$
Integration over the interval from $x$ to $y$ gives
$$
               |f(x)-f(y)| \le M|x-y|,\;\; |f'(x)-f'(y)|\le M|x-y|,\;\;\mbox{ for all } x,y\in[0,1],\;f\in A.
$$